# How can I replace every letter from a string with a '-' except for the variable character? (Python)

Tags: python

I want to replace every character in a string with a '-' except for the entered variable.

For example, if guessedLetter = h, the string 'house' would become 'h----'

Comment: can you elaborate your question? the guessed letter is user input or how you are getting these letters??

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension

```
guessedLetter = 'h'
string = 'house' 
new = ''.join(['-' if let != guessedLetter else guessedLetter for let in string])
```

output

```
h----
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `regex`:

```
import re

guessedLetter = 'o'
s = 'house'
result = re.sub(f'[^{guessedLetter}]', '-', s)
```